# knapsack algorithm with two weights

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, greedy

I have questions which is the following:

> Solve the knapsack 0-1 problem(not fractional) Assuming that every
>   object have weight `w1` or `w2` (there only two weights). Capacity=W, the algorithm
>   must run on O(nlogn).

I tried to solve, the greedy algorithm doesn't work, the dynamic programming algorithm is O(n*W).

Can anyone give me hint.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide the elements in 2 parts, one that have `w1` as weight and the other that have `w2` as weight.

Now you can sort the two lists above according to their costs.

> A1 : sorted by cost in descending order, elements that have weight as w1
>
> A2 : sorted by cost in descending order, elements that have weight as w2

Now you can create prefix sum of both the array lets call them `P1, P2`.

example :

`Array      : 11,  8,  5,  3,  1`

`Prefix sum : 11, 19, 24, 27, 28`

Once you have the prefix sum, you can iterate over the `P1` array and try to include elements upto the ith index.
Once we include elements upto `i`, we have `W - (w1*i)` weight left we can then try to binary search this weight in the `P2` array.

Pseudo code :

```
A : input array
create A1 : cost of elements having w1 weight
create A2 : cost of elements having w2 weight

sort(A1, descending)
sort(A2, descending)

for(i=0;i <= A1.size();i++){
      P1[i] = P1[i-1] + A1[i];
      P2[i] = P2[i-1] + A2[i];
}
int ans = 0;
for(i=1;i<=A1.size();i++){
      if(i * w1 <= W){
            int wLeft = W - i * w1;
            int ans = binarySearch(wLeft, P2) + p1[i];  
      }
}
ans => contains the answer

//-----------Binary search function
int binarySearch(int weight, P2[]){
      int start = 0, end = P2.size(), ans = 0;
      int mid = (start+end)/2;
      while(start <= end){
            if(mid * w2 <= weight){
                  start = mid + 1;
                  ans = max(ans, p2[mid]);
            }else{
                  end = mid - 1;
            }
      }
return ans
}
```

The overall complexity is `O(n * log n)`.

As suggested by @j_random_hacker we can iterate over the second prefix array, as we can only improve the solution by adding elements, it would simplify the code by removing the binary search.

Comment: This looks like the only solution that takes values/costs into account (in fairness the OP could have been clearer that the problem includes these).  You can replace the binary search in the inner loop with a pointer j that walks backwards from the end of P2, though this won't improve the time complexity because the sorting still dominates.

Comment: I think there are some typos in this algorithm: `P1[i] = P[i-1] + A1[i];` - shouldn't it be `P1[i] = P1[i-1] + A1[i];`? (and the same goes for next line). Also, I'm not sure that `ans` mechanism is accurate. Finally, is it possible that the `binarySearch` is missing something in the `else` branch? But, maybe I'm wrong :-)

Comment: @Zvika Thanks for pointing out the typo fixed it. Why do you think the ans mechanism is not accurate can you provide some sample cases for which it might fail? I don't think that there is anything missing in the else case, it would be nice if you could point out some concrete mistakes with it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are two weights you can:

First use as many elements w1 as you have or can fit in W. After them as many w2 as possible.

When you get such knapsack, in every iteration pop one w1 element from it, and put as many w2 as can fit or you have. You do this as long as you have w1 elements in knapsack.

Maximum weight of knapsack from all iterations will be you anwser and algorithm will run in O(n)